# TFS 2017 update 3.1 doesn't have a uninstall option

Tags: tfs

I was trying to uninstall TFS 217 update 3.1 going through the control panel ->uninstall a program . When I click on TFS 2017 update 3.1 I am getting only change option not getting uninstall option. How to uninstall ?

Comment: Yes, Now I am able to uninstall , Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not uninstall TFS server from control panel--Programs and Features. Use the unconfigure instead, it's similar to the way we usually uninstall other software.

To "**Unconfigure TFS**", please go to the Team Foundation Administration Console on the Application Tier machine. Click on the server name and click on "Remove Feature"

[image]

**By Removing the feature, we will be removing**

- The Application Tier configuration from the server (but we don't
  remove the binaries)
- Connection with Data tier (but the databases won’t be deleted)
- TFS Website.
- TFS Application Pools
- TFS Services (The Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Job Agent)

You can do the same from command prompt, execute `TfsConfig setup /uninstall:ApplicationTier` command to unconfigure TFS Application Tier. (You can also use various switches to remove other features SharePointExtensions, TeamBuild and VersionControlP
roxy) from server machine.

Usually we'd like to refresh the TFS Application Tier setup to defaults in case there's an unintended change in services/IIS settings and we want to set it back to defaults. We give an option to Remove Application Tier/Features without having to uninstall the complete application.

Another usage is when you are using pre-upgrade for test, you could quickly remove Application Tier. Since everything have been migrated, if you don't need the TFS server any more, just simply uninstall the complete application and database.You could back up your database, once you want to use again. Just install a new application and restore your database.

Hope this helps.